# Xcode 7 + swift. "Use of local variable '_' before its declaration" Error

Tags: ios, swift

I get the above error when trying to create a function to check user inputs and store data. My project builds fine until I reach this function `RegisterButtonTapped()`. Does anyone have some structural or syntax changes that could get rid of this error?

```
   @IBAction func RegisterButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userRepeatPassword = userRepeatPasswordTextField.text;


    // Check for empty fields
    if(userEmail!.isEmpty || userPassword!.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword!.isEmpty){

        displayAlertMessage("All fields are required");

        return;
    }

    // Check if passwords match
    if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword){

        displayAlertMessage("Passwords do not match");

        return;
    }

    // Store Data
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userEmail, forKey: "userEmail");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userEmail, forKey: "userPassword");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

    // Display Alert message with confirmation
    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert",message:"Registration is successful, thank you.",preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    func displayAlertMessage(userMessage:String){

        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert",message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"ok",style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil);

        myAlert.addAction(okAction);
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
    } // END OF FUNCTION 'displayAlertMessage()'



} // END of FUNCTION 'RegisterButtonTapped()'
```

Comment: Side note - I already tried cleaning + rebuilding the project, and restarting Xcode.

Comment: you have defined `displayAlertMessage` inside `RegisterButtonTapped`... Also use came case for function names.

Comment: @triple.s Swift has nested function

Answer (score 0):

You have declared displayAlertMessage after you are calling it, move the declaration of it near the top of RegisterButtonTapped() if you want to keep it as a nested function, otherwise move it out of RegisterButtonTapped().

Apart from that you have two variables both called myAlert, the first is useless, and you are saving userEmail as both the email and the password, also calling synchronize() is not required.

Answer (score 0):

There are some details to get it running right. The `displayAlertMessage` was declared inside the register function after the calling and like that we get the warning. When you get success, you must call the function with the success message, and not declaring `var myAlert` like inside the alert function. And final detail: when getting the UITextFields values, you got email input field and set it to password value, so the validation will be wrong.

Here a sample of code that works great:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var userEmailTextField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var userPassTextField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var userRepeatPasswordTextField:UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func RegisterButtonTapped(sender:UIButton) {
        let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
        let userPassword = userPassTextField.text;
        let userRepeatPassword = userRepeatPasswordTextField.text;


        // Check for empty fields
        if(userEmail!.isEmpty || userPassword!.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword!.isEmpty){

            displayAlertMessage("All fields are required");

            return;
        }

        // Check if passwords match
        if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword){

            displayAlertMessage("Passwords do not match");

            return;
        }

        // Store Data
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userEmail, forKey: "userEmail");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userEmail, forKey: "userPassword");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

        displayAlertMessage("Registration is successful, thank you.")
    }

    // Display Alert message with confirmation
    func displayAlertMessage(userMessage:String){

        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert",message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"ok",style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil);

        myAlert.addAction(okAction);
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }

}
```

Comment: "The displayAlertMessage was declared inside the register function and like that we get the warning". That is not the case, a nested function is allowed with Swift.

Comment: Forgot to say the declaration was after the calling. Made the changes.

Comment: Your improvements worked perfectly. Code is running as expected now.

Comment: Great @TomDelFranco. Approve the answer so, please.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a nested function, you have to declare it *before* you can call it. In this case, move the "displayAlertMessage(userMessage:String)" function above the "// Check for empty fields" comment, then it should compile.